# php exec() command failing to run php script on server

Tags: php, server

I have the following command in a php script that is executed after pressing a button on my website:

```
exec('nohup php /var/www/website.org.uk/myScript.php >> /var/www/website.org.uk/shared/storage/logs/myLog.log 2>&1 & echo $! > /var/www/website.org.uk/pid.txt');
```

Ideally, on my server it should execute `myScript.php`, send any output from the script to `myLog.log` and store the pid of the `myScript.php` process to `pid.txt`.

myScript.php:

```
<?php
print "\nStarting dummy script\n";
sleep(10); // Sleep for 10 seconds.
print "\nFinished dummy script\n";
```

If I ssh into the server and run the command manually, it all works fine. When run from the website however, the pid is written to the `pid.txt` file, but the php script fails immediately. Nothing is written to the log, and I can't see the process running on the server when using the `ps` command (I should see it running for at least 10 seconds due to the sleep command).

After reading previous stack overflow posts I changed permissions for all three files to `-rwxr-x---` and updated the group to `www-data` but this didn't made any difference.

Am I missing anything else here?

Comment: I think you cannot assume that your webhost will allow you to `nohup` a task... Are you sure they do allow nohup?

Comment: it have no permission to write to group: `chmod g+w`

Comment: It was just a permissions issue. Thanks for the help